# IF statement or something else I haven't thought of?

Tags: java, android

I'm making a long exposure calculator, this allows the user to input their current shutter speed, select a EV (exposure value) and then click calculate to work out an equivalent exposure.

Both the current shutter speed and the desired EV change are selected from spinners as you can see here:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14064960/2013-04-17%2011.31.47.png

The resulting equivalent exposure is dependent on the two variables.

For example:

Current Shutter Speed: 1/100
EV: +1
Equivalent Shutter Speed = 1/50

Current Shutter Speed: 1/100
EV: +2
Equivalent Shutter Speed = 1/25

The only way I've worked out how to do this for all the variables is a **MASSIVE** IF statement listing all possible combinations:

```
If shutter speed is 1/100 and EV is +2, then equivalent shutter speed is 1/25.
```

There are 20 different shutter speeds and 10 different EV values, so that's going to be loads of IFs.

Anybody have a better idea about how I could possibly do this?

I'm not after full code but rather psuedo code or a way to do it so I can work it out myself, thanks.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

***EDIT:***

The formula to work it out is that for each EV increment the shutter speed has to double, but this is complicated because the format of the shutter speed changes.

1/4000, 1/2000, 1/1000, 1/500, 1/250, 1/125, 1/60, 1/30, 1/15, 1/8, ¼, ½, 1 sec, 2 sec, 4 sec, 8 sec, 15 sec, 30 sec, 1 min 2 min, 4 min, 8 min etc

**EDIT:**

Existing code as requested:

**Layout:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fabricc"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".ExpCalc" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/apertureexample"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:contentDescription="Aperture Example Image"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/longexpcalc" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Current Shutter Speed:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/Locationspinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:entries="@array/shutterspeeds_array"
            android:padding="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout04"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout0f4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="EV Adjustment:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1233"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="(+6 = 6-stop ND Filter)"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    </LinearLayout>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/evLocationspinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:entries="@array/ev_array"
            android:padding="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/CalculateEquivExposure"
        style="@style/sub_menu"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_menu_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Calculate Equivelent Exposure" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/equivexp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="40dp"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            android:text="1/8000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Java:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class ExpCalc extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.expcalc);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        setupActionBar();
    }

    //Sets up Action Bar
    private void setupActionBar() {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    //Sets up buttons in the quick menu
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.LessonsTutorials) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Lessons.class));
        }
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.PhotoTools) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Tools.class));
        }
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.Glossary) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Glossary.class));
        }
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.Help) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Help.class));
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

String arrays:

```
<string-array name="shutterspeeds_array">
    <item>1/8000</item>
    <item>1/4000</item>
    <item>1/2000</item>
    <item>1/1000</item>
    <item>1/500</item>
    <item>1/250</item>
    <item>1/125</item>
    <item>1/60</item>
    <item>1/30</item>
    <item>1/15</item>
    <item>1/8</item>
    <item>1/4</item>
    <item>1/2</item>
    <item>1 sec</item>
    <item>2 sec</item>
    <item>4 sec</item>
    <item>8 sec</item>
    <item>15 sec</item>
    <item>30 sec</item>
    <item>1 min</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="ev_array">
    <item>0</item>
    <item>+1</item>
    <item>+2</item>
    <item>+3</item>
    <item>+4</item>
    <item>+5</item>
    <item>+6</item>
    <item>+7</item>
    <item>+8</item>
    <item>+9</item>
    <item>+10</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: Is there any formula to calculate these values?

Comment: I would need to know how shutter speed and EV are combined to create equivalent shutter speed.

Comment: there must be a formula as Egor asked.  If not then switch statement would reduce your amount of work.

Comment: If there wasn't a formula, you could create a table in sqllite and store the equivalences and get the result with a query, that's easy to mantain and doesn't make the behaviour that code-dependant.

Comment: I framed this formula from the available data in the OP : **current shutter speed = (x amounts of EV)* (y*2 amounts of equivalent shutter speed)** ?

Comment: Yeah the formula is quite simple, the shutter speed doubles in value with every EV stop increased. The problem is that the shutter speed goes from 1/10 to 1 sec to 1 min format.

Comment: @Athoul, The idea is if there is a formula and you can express it in code - then it's the right way to go.

Comment: But the formula isn't simple due to how the format of the shutter speed changes.

Comment: Do the formatting after working out the value.  ESS = SS * (EV + 1)

Comment: Keep it in seconds. When you return current shutter speed, if speed > 60, then divide by 60 for number of minutes... if < 1, then display it as a fraction.

Comment: @BryanDenny - But would that handle the fractions correctly?

Comment: Here is some C code (I got the equation wrong before) - http://codepad.org/Y7lW0W0f

Comment: alternatively, add the index of `ev_array` to the index of `shutterspeeds_array`

Comment: Does it really double or does it follow your spinner?  I.E. Given SS = 1/30 and EV = +2, is ESS = 1/8 or 2/15?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28381/discussion-between-spacedmonkey-and-athoul)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont wanna provide a full code to copy, because if you are doing this for a school project, i'd rather help you develop the answer with our help.

Here's a pretty simple solution:

Since all you need is these exact values you can work with incremting a counter in a String array. This solution only works if there is a clear max shutterspeed.

```
String[] shutterSpeedValues={"1/4000", "1/2000", etc. }
```

Then you can set the SpinnerAdapter of the first spinner to use this Array.

For the Second Spinner just do the same but map [0] to 0 and [1] to +1 etc.

So you end up with:

```
shutterSpeedValues[]
eVValues[]
```

When the user presses the Calculate button get the item ids of the selected values in the Spinner. you end up with for example

```
shutterSpeedItemId="3"
evValueItemId="4"
```

This would correspond to a user who selected "1/500" and "+4"

now what you do is:

```
   int eqExposureItemId = shutterSpeedItemId+evValueItemId;
   String eqExposure = shutterSpeedValues[eqExposureItemId];
   mySolutionTextView.setText(eqExposure);
```

*4+3=7 --> 1/30*

What you still need is a solution for high values in both Spinners (dont get an ArrayOutOfBoundsError). There are fixes for that, but try to get it to work like this first.

**EDIT:** below is the full code of this solution.

**Activity**

```
   package com.yallatschikowski.exposurecalculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ExposureCalculatorActivity extends Activity {

    Spinner shutterSpinner;
    Spinner evSpinner;
    String[] shutterValues;
    String[] evValues;
    Button calcButton;
    TextView resultTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exposure_calculator);

        // connect the variables to the layout
        shutterSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.shutterSpinner);
        evSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.evSpinner);
        shutterValues = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.shutterspeeds_array);
        evValues = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ev_array);
        calcButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcBT);
        resultTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTV);

        addItemsOnSpinner();
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    private void addListenerOnButton() {
        calcButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int resultID = calculatExposure();

                // check if the resultID is too big
                if (resultID < shutterValues.length) {
                    resultTextView.setText(shutterValues[resultID]);
                } else {
                    resultTextView.setText("Value > 1min");
                }
            }
        });

    }

    protected int calculatExposure() {

        long shutterID = shutterSpinner.getSelectedItemId();
        long evID = evSpinner.getSelectedItemId();
        return (int) (shutterID + evID);
    }

    private void addItemsOnSpinner() {

        ArrayAdapter<String> shutterAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, shutterValues);
        shutterAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        shutterSpinner.setAdapter(shutterAdapter);

        ArrayAdapter<String> evAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, evValues);
        evAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        evSpinner.setAdapter(evAdapter);
    }

}
```

**I also changed some things around in the Layout(mainly ID's), posting it to be complete**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".ExpCalc" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Current Shutter Speed:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/shutterSpinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"


            android:padding="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout04"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="EV Adjustment:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/evSpinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"

            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="(+6 = 6-stop ND Filter)"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/calcBT"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Calculate Equivelent Exposure" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resultTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="40dp"
            android:textSize="35sp"
             />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No, its perfectly fine to have the arrays in the xml (actually its better then having it in the code) and doing `String[] shutterSpeedValues=getResources().getStringArray(R.id.shutterspeeds_array)`. Since i've also read in the chat you are very new to this whole thing, I'll try to update my answer with proper code if i find the time for it in the next 24 hours.

Comment: I've edited my answer and it now contains the solution in fully functional code. If you have problems getting it to work with your Layout, feel free to message me. And if you get it to work, please acceppt this answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Store the shutter speeds in a list.
2. Get the index of the correct shutter speed.
3. Add your EV value to the index.
4. Pull the correct speed out of the list at that new index.

ymmv

Comment: This is a simple solution that will work. All you need to do is Exception Handling when index+ Ev value > list size and if you also have negative EV value, if index + ev value < 0 .

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a table?

```
currentShutterSpeed = table[evID][eqShutterSpeedID];
```

where  and  are the IDs that correspond to indices into the table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to consider the alternative of storing the dataset in a database, sqllite is the answer for Android. In order not to copy-paste a tutorial into the site, here's a link of a good guide you could use to implement some basic database access:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Hope this helps in case you cannot just calculate the value. I know there are formulas, but sometimes you use rounded or approximate values from standard tables and it might be easier having the tables on some database.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Nested Switch Statements can be a way of reducing your if else ladder.Like have a Switch Case for Current Shutter Speed then with in that case Switch  for Equivalent Shutter Speed.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to use the decorator pattern. That way you can add behaviour to an individual object. So you decorate the shutter speed with the EV. More information [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).